# How to change the command prompt of WinGHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci

Windows 10 x64, Haskell

I created `%appdata%\ghc\ghci.conf` file and added into it the command for prompt changing:

```
:set prompt "\x03BB"
```

I see it was applied only for `ghci.exe` and `ghci-8.0.1.exe`, but `WinGHCi` prompt wasn't changed:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have this problem: https://github.com/haskell/winghci/issues/7

Also:

> The original author is no longer active with the project, but the code
>   is still maintained. Please submit your pull requests here.

Therefore I will not learn this tool now.